# Apps Script for Google Sheets (onedit function)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

On google sheets trying to hide/unhide rows based on the values in particular cells, and trying to write a script in AppsScript for that. Found that one that works in isolation (if B55=NO it hides 64 next rows):

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = e.range; 
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== 'Inputs' || range.getA1Notation() !== 'B55') return; 
  if (e.value === 'No') { 
    activeSheet.hideRows(56, 64);
  }  else if (e.value === 'Yes') { 
      activeSheet.showRows(56, 64); 
      } 
}
```

But I need the same for Multiple Cells and multiple rows, as soon as I expand it only last part of the code works and not the first:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = e.range; 
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== 'Inputs' || range.getA1Notation() !== 'B55') return; 
  if (e.value === 'No') { 
    activeSheet.hideRows(56, 64);
  }  else if (e.value === 'Yes') { 
      activeSheet.showRows(56, 64); 
      } 
}
function onEdit(e) { 
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = e.range; 
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== 'Inputs' || range.getA1Notation() !== 'B121') return; 
  if (e.value === 'No') { 
    activeSheet.hideRows(122, 67);
  }  else if (e.value === 'Yes') { 
      activeSheet.showRows(122, 67); 
      } 
}
```

From here Cell B121 is working, but my B55 Stops working. Any tips? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the 2 functions onEdit, try

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = e.range; 
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== 'Inputs') return; 
  if (range.getA1Notation() == 'B55'){ 
    if (e.value === 'No') { 
      activeSheet.hideRows(56, 64);
    }  else if (e.value === 'Yes') { 
      activeSheet.showRows(56, 64); 
    } 
  }
  if (range.getA1Notation() == 'B121') { 
    if (e.value === 'No') { 
      activeSheet.hideRows(122, 67);
    }  else if (e.value === 'Yes') { 
      activeSheet.showRows(122, 67); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: ye i guess, that's what i can't figure out on how to do

Comment: sorry haven't realized u attached a code there, it works, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Mike is correct, you can only have on onEdit() trigger, but cannot just merge as he shows since there are returns if the condition is not found

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = e.range; 
  if (activeSheet.getName() == 'Inputs' && range.getA1Notation() == 'B55') {; 
    if (e.value === 'No') { 
      activeSheet.hideRows(56, 64);
    }  else if (e.value === 'Yes') { 
        activeSheet.showRows(56, 64); 
        } 
  }
  if (activeSheet.getName() == 'Inputs' && range.getA1Notation() == 'B121') { 
    if (e.value === 'No') { 
      activeSheet.hideRows(122, 67);
    }  else if (e.value === 'Yes') { 
        activeSheet.showRows(122, 67); 
      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, both yours and Mike's codes work, I am probably not good enough to understand the difference. B55 can only be yes/no (from drop down) if that's what you meant by "conditions not met", that's why either code works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, after reviewing Mike's suggestion it is just fine, I saw the "return" and did not realize he changed it from the way you used the return (!==).

Answer (score 0):

Answers have already been provided, but consider the more general case:

```js
function myFooBar() { 
  console.log("the first one") 
}

function myFooBar() { 
  console.log("the second one") 
}

function doMyFooBar() {
  myFooBar();
}
```

When you run `doMyFooBar()`, the console shows `the second one`. Reading from the top of the script to the bottom, the last declaration of `function myFooBar()` replaces any previous declarations of that function.